# FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = '/storage/0/emulated/myfolder/myfile.txt' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I trying to create a folder inside Internal Storage and create a file there but getting error: `FileSystemException (FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = '/storage/0/emulated/myfolder/myfile.txt' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2))`

Here is my function to get the directory:

```
 Future<String> get _path async {
final _dir = Directory('/storage/0/emulated/myfolder');
if (await _dir.exists()) {
  return _dir.path;
}
_dir.create();
return _dir.path;}
```

Here is function to write to file:

```
Future<void> writeToFile(String text) async {
var file = File('${await _path}/myfile.txt');
print(file);
await file.writeAsString(text);
print(await file.readAsString());
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mistaken the file path.

The starting path should be `/storage/emulated/0/`

There is no such thing as `/storage/0/emulated/`